# Auto refresh table by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to make a table in an HTML/PHP page auto refresh every 10 seconds. In this table, a chart from Google Spreadsheet is embedded. What am I doing wrong?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z3tfw37e/)

```
var counter = 0;
window.setInterval("refreshDiv()", 10000);
function refreshDiv(){
    counter = counter + 1;
    document.getElementById("google");
}
```

Comment: You're aren't doing a refresh at all. You're only getting the id of the div.

Comment: refreshDiv() can`t refresh div? :(

Comment: This is [fixed code](https://jsfiddle.net/z3tfw37e/5/), unwraping it form onload wrapper (jsFiddle feature). But your code is doing nothing, so....  And calling a method refreshDiv() when there is no DIV seems quite unrelevant, isn't it?!....  You want to refresh the iframe or what?

Comment: And increasing the counter that's it. Addition to jay's comment.

Comment: Yes, I want refres iframe from google chart.

Answer (score 0):

[As per documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) setInterval() receives two parameters. The first one is a function and the second one is milliseconds to wait till next execution.

You're passing a string as the first parameter. Here you are a way where refreshDiv function gets executed.

```
var counter = 0;

var refreshDiv = function () {
  console.log( 'Hey! I was called!!!' );
  counter = counter + 1;
  document.getElementById( "google" );
}

window.setInterval(refreshDiv, 10000);
```